# Are questions about the software centre app submit process acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this question OK, I'm not sure wether it is on or off topic?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/493118/ubuntu-software-center-app-pending-review

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions about "why wasn't my app accepted/rejected" or "what's the status of my app" should be addressed by the representatives of Canonical. We've consistently closing them as we really can't help those users. There's a contact form in the bottom of the Canonical page which should be used.

Comment: You commented about the contact form on the question, but didn't specify where... there are quite a lot of forms that could be used.

Comment: @Wilf I don't have a developer account, but I remember dobey commenting on that matter.

Comment: Agreed. I've pointed people toward the canonical contact page here: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us  This is a case where a simple google search containing the words canonical contact is all that is required to get started.

Answer (score -2):

Sure the question is acceptable. And if the answer is useful to others, then it should stand. It might well be duplicated a million times, so the pointer to the original answer (which should include a link to Canonical) will be a good answer.

If the question is duplicated a million times, then I guess it qualifies as a Frequently Asked Question, and the answer would appear in the FAQ.

Pogo.